# Passing php variables to javascript function on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, variables, popup, href

I have a php page that recalls data from an SQL table, and then displays them.
I am trying to create a popup page to view tables related to a piece of data in the table(normalized database).
I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.
my current php table display is
where $result is a mysqli query array

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['first_name']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['last_name']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['grade']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['gpaP']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['AGP']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['rigorP']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['APP']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['formID']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['total']}</td>"; 
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['date']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['IP']}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

and

```
echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'>{$row['formID']}</td>";
```

is what I need to change into a hotlink for a popup box. The popup's href should be "activities.php?form_id={$formID}" but I can't figure out a way to do this while dealing with all the collisions with the php and everything.
What i was trying to do was making a link like

```
echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'><a href=\"javascript:win1()\">asdfasd<a/></td>";
```

and then creating a javascript function like

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function win1() {
    window.open("activities.php?form_ID={$formID}","Window1","menubar=no,width=460,height=360,toolbar=no");
}
</script>
```

but this does not work because the $formID variable isnt getting loaded for some reason. If i try to get the variable from activities.php like

```
$getvar = $_GET['form_ID'];
```

and then

```
echo $getvar;
```

it displays nothing..
Someone please help me, I think my head is going to burst..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your function to

```
function win1(formID) {
    window.open("activities.php?form_ID="+formID,"Window1","menubar=no,width=460,height=360,toolbar=no");
}
```

and your PHP to

```
echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'><a href=\"javascript:win1($formID)\">asdfasd<a/></td>";
```

Comment: after i GET the variable in activities.php the echo is displaying "undefined"

Comment: how are you getting your `formID`? Maybe it should be `win1($row['formID']`

Comment: Yes! Check your browser [inspect element] and check the generated href value

Comment: IT WORKS OH YES THANK YOU SO MUCH! this was keeping me crazy for the whole day... If i could give you 10000 points i would.. THank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You can use inside the `while`:

```
echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;'><a href=\"javascript:win1('{$row['formID']}')\">asdfasd<a/></td>";
```

and function outside that `while`:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function win1(frmid) {
    window.open("activities.php?form_ID="+frmid,"Window1","menubar=no,width=460,height=360,toolbar=no");
}
</script>
```